# Slick Try(query(run)) always return success

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I was using slick 3.2.1. I use operatorId as Foreign Key.

My code is something like that

```
def changeCommentStatus(changeRequest: StatusUpdateRequest(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Int] = {
    val changeStatusQuery = comments
      .filter(_.id inSetBind changeRequest.commentIds)
      .filter(_.status === changeRequest.prevStatus)
      .map(c => (c.operatorId, c.updatedAt, c.status))
      .update((Some(changeRequest.operatorId), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())), changeRequest.status))
    db.run(changeStatusQuery)
  }
Try(changeCommentStatus(changeRequest)) match {
      case Success(response) => bla bla bla
      case Failure(f) => bla bla bla
```

I use operatorId which violate Foreign Key but Try cannot be failure. How can i fix that?

Comment: dont see anything related to postgres

Comment: i added because also exist similar name js tool named slick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DBIOAction#asTry`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/api/index.html#slick.dbio.DBIOAction@asTry:slick.dbio.DBIOAction[scala.util.Try[R],slick.dbio.NoStream,E]) to convert the `DBIOAction[Int]` to a `DBIOAction[Try[Int]]`, then `flatMap` the result:

```
def changeCommentStatus(...): Future[Int] = {
  val changeStatusQuery = comments
    .filter(...)
    .filter(...)
    .map(...)
    .update(...)
    .asTry
    .flatMap {
      case Success(res) => DBIO.successful(res)
      case Failure(t)   => DBIO.failed(t)
    }

  db.run(changeStatusQuery)
}
```

Then you can pattern match on the `Future` in the following manner:

```
changeCommentStatus(changeRequest).onComplete {
  case Success(response) => ...
  case Failure(t)        => ...
}
```

Comment: It fix my issue. Thanks a lot :D